# React Testing by jsdom - unable to get a class which is dynamically inserted into dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I am testing a react based grid component by mocha and jsdom. There is an options button on the grid which on mouseDown generates a popup within the grid. Now I can simulate the mouseDown by `TestUtils.Simulate` and also verified that the function is getting called, but I am unable to get the class of the generated popup by `TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass`. The popup does not fade away untill the user clicks outside of the grid. What should be the approach? Is there is any way I can print the jsdom markup so that I can inspect further?

Comment: You can print the dom wrapped by jsdom by using something like `console.log(jsdom.serializeDocument(window.document))`.

Comment: did that, just getting the bootstrapped html like `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Are you actually rendering the component? `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(myElement)`?

Comment: yes, into jsdom. my other tests are working ok